# WebAPI OutputCache cache invalidation

Tags: caching, asp.net-web-api, cache-control, outputcache

I have the following caching attribute on my controller method:

```
 [CacheOutput(ClientTimeSpan = 14400, ServerTimeSpan = 14400)]
```

I am attempting to clear the cache. However, after running this line of code:

```
 //clear cache   
 cache.RemoveStartsWith(Configuration.CacheOutputConfiguration().MakeBaseCachekey("BeamsController", "Get"));
```

I am still getting a 304 not-modified response without the controller method being invoked.

I am using this library https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache

Answer (score 3):

```
 [InvalidateCacheOutput("Get", typeof(BeamsController))]
```

seems to work, instead of 'manual invalidation' (`RemoveStartsWith`), above.

In fact, after reading the source code of the attribute, it appears that the documentation is wrong and it should be:

```
cache.RemoveStartsWith(Configuration.CacheOutputConfiguration().MakeBaseCachekey("Beams", "Get"));
```

which works as expected, calling the method.