# Which headers allow a browser to reuse a file from cache without contacting the server at all?

Tags: http, browser-cache, cache-control, http-caching

Conversely, which headers cause a browser to contact the server the next time around to check if the cached file is still valid?

```
Cache-Control:max-age=14400
Content-Length:1375502
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Wed, 04 Feb 2015 20:51:47 GMT
ETag:"b88aa553-6456-4844-b5bc-173ad8b9e0a1"
```

Above headers are from the original request. When I re-request it, I get a 304.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [RFC 7234: Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Caching, section 4.2. Freshness](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.2):

> A fresh response is one whose age has not yet exceeded its freshness
> lifetime.  Conversely, a stale response is one where it has.

> A response's freshness lifetime is the length of time between its
> generation by the origin server and its expiration time.  An explicit
> expiration time is the time at which the origin server intends that a
> stored response can no longer be used by a cache without further
> validation, whereas a heuristic expiration time is assigned by a
> cache when no explicit expiration time is available.

> A response's age is the time that has passed since it was generated
> by, or successfully validated with, the origin server.

> When a response is "fresh" in the cache, it **can** be used to satisfy
> subsequent requests **without contacting the origin server**, thereby
> improving efficiency.

> The primary mechanism for determining freshness is for an origin
> server to provide an explicit expiration time in the future, **using
> either the Expires header field ([Section 5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.3)) or the max-age response
> directive ([Section 5.2.2.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2.2.8))**.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why, in the above case, a request is made to the server (instead of just using the cache) ; I have added the headers - Is it just implementation specific?

Comment: Ah, so you changed your question. ;) [How do you refresh](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3401049/chrome-doesnt-cache-images-js-css)?

Comment: Jacob Krall's answer in the question you linked provided the answer, max-age:0 was in the request headers because I was pressing enter in the address bar in Chrome.  Thanks.

Comment: Although this is the question I'm really struggling with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325060/webapi-outputcache-cache-invalidation

Comment: I don't know that library, so I wouldn't know where to look.